# Redirect files and folders matching a prefix pattern

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all requests to subfolders and subfiles in a directory that start with 4 numbers (e.g. 2012) to another directory using the .htaccess file.

For example,

```
/results/2005-09-19-xxx/* to /event/2005-09-19-xxx/*
```

and

```
/results/2005-09-20-file.ext to /event/2005-09-20-file.ext
```

But not

```
/results/anything-else/*
```

From the documents I have looked at I believe I need to use a RewriteCond followed by a RewriteRule. I have been struggling to find a way to both match on the initial 4 numbers and still use them in the redirected link.

I have spent many hours trying to find a solution to this issue, any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't realy need a rewrite condition, try this rewrite rule :

```
RewriteRule ^results/([0-9]{4}.*)$ /event/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^result/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})(.+)$ event/$1-$2-$3$4 [L]
```

This pattern is: 4 numbers dash 2 numbers dash 2 numbers rest, written in a way that you can easily understand and manipulate at a later date if need be. Everything that fits the pattern will be rewritten - the rest will work as it normally does

Example:

```
result/2012-02-02-abcd.ext
```

fits the pattern and will be rewritten to

```
event/2012-02-02-abcd.ext
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, I've now got it working, cheers.